# How does this implicit declaration of generics work in java?

Tags: java, generics

I have this declaration

```
private ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
```

where `ObservableList` is `import javafx.collections.ObservableList;` and class is like this

`public interface ObservableList<E> extends List<E>, Observable`

So my question is how this implicit declaration of `E` works. What is `E` inside `E`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is how this implicit declaration of E works. What is E inside E?

It doesn't, not really.

The `E` in this case is the raw type `ObservableList`; and [you shouldn't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Raw types are a concession to retain backwards-compatibility with pre-generics code, and shouldn't be used unless you have to interface with code that uses raw types.

In this case, the issue is that if you get an element of `data`, e.g. `data.get(0)`, that is a raw-typed `ObservableList`, so you can do things with it that aren't type safe, such as adding elements to the list of the wrong type.